# Fastest way to create dataframe from hundreds csv files

Tags: python, pandas

I have 150 csv files with two column (time and site). I want to read each file, creating frequency dictionary ({'site':[site_number, number of occurrences site]}) and creating DataFrame consists of 11 columns (user_id, site1, site2, ...site10), user_id parsing from name of file (../user0001.csv). Each row in DataFrame unique session of 10 site visits. My codes worked on 150 files 150 seconds (its terrible). How can i improve it?

```
def prepare_3(path_to_csv_files, session_length=10):
  word_freq = {}
  freq_dict = {}
  word_count = 0
  row = []

  columns = []
  columns.append('user_id')
  columns.extend(['site' + str(i) for i in range(1, session_length+1)])

  lst_files = sorted(glob(path_to_csv_files))

  for csv in lst_files:
    user = int(csv[csv.find('.')-4:csv.find('.')])
    frame = []
    frame.append(user) 
    site_count = 0

    with open(csv, 'r') as f:
      f.readline()
      for line in f:
        site = line[line.find(',') + 1:].rstrip()
        site_count += 1

        if site in word_freq:
          word_freq[site][1] += 1
        else:
          word_count += 1
          word_freq[site] = [word_count, 1]

        if site_count > session_length:
          site_count = 1
          row.append(frame)
          frame = []
          frame.append(user) 
          frame.append(word_freq[site][0])
        else:
          frame.append(word_freq[site][0])

    row.append(frame)
  df = pd.DataFrame(data=row, columns=columns, dtype=int)
  df.fillna(0 ,inplace=True)
  return df, word_freq
```

Comment: Might look into Dask

Comment: I would suggest `dask.dataframe`, except for the requirement that the filename is stored for each file within the dataframe. I never found a way to do that bit.